# Php form doesn't work until second button click

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a follow button so that when the user clicks the button it creates a object/term relationship with the author. Anyways i'm using the form below so that when the user clicks the button it executes the php code, anyways the code below works, but only when you click the button the second time. The first time it does nothing for some reason. Thanks, Julian

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['select']))
 {
   $author_id = get_the_author_meta( 'nickname' );
   $user_id = get_current_user_id();
   $term_ids = wp_set_object_terms( $user_id, $author_id, 'user_follow', true );
 }

?>

<html>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="select" value="select"/>
</form>
```

Comment: server request uri is the same page as you are on, without the action attribute the form should submit to the same page anyway. do you really need to access the $_SERVER there?

Comment: I want it to pretty much refresh the page when the button is clicked, it doesn't work with action="" either

Comment: try changeing the name.. name="something" value="somethingelse" just to test and change the $_POST part too obviously. my thinking is "select" might be somehow conflicting things.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no luck

Comment: Try adding an echo in your if and see if it really does take two clicks

Comment: What do I echo? I added a var dump, and this is what was returned array(1) { ["select"]=> string(6) "Submit" }

Comment: some key information missing here, what is supposed to change when you `wp_set_object_terms` and where is it in relation to the code above? It sounds like you are submitting + the page reloads, generates the html you want changed, reaches the php `$_POST` code and then your form, in which case, it would take another page refresh to make the changes.